# ZPL to print strike through

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

Is there a way to use ZPL to print text with a strikethrough (a line through the text)?

I need to be able to print something and indicate that it was there.  I have looked through the ZPL programming guide and I have not found any way to alter the font....

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach would be to draw a line through your text.  Here is a sample.  You would need to calculate the points of the line based on the coordinates of the text:

```
^XA
^FT62,93^A0N,42,40^FH\^FDstrikethrough^FS
^FO41,76^GB268,0,5^FS
^PQ1
^XZ
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIAA, No.

Could you simply draw a line over the required text? Perhaps you could use or manufacture a downloaded bitmap font which is "struck through?"

---

OTOH...

To underline - use a monospaced font like AA,AC,AD,AF or AG

Use

```
^FO350,50^AGR^FDwhatever,milk,butter,salt^FS
^FO340,50^AGR^FD         ____ ______^FS
```

where the underline here is under milk and butter, you can adjust the offset by trimming the FO's X and Y positions by a few dots (10 X here). Naturally, that can be raised for strikethrough, too...